# Passing down props resulting from an async API call : getting undefined

Tags: vue.js

I started using single file components in Vue to try and be more modular with them, and I have difficulties passing down props when they are set by an async response from an API.

Here is exactly what i'm working on :

- [parent component](http://pastebin.com/TaRw6H17)
- [child component](http://pastebin.com/niQ6Erbt)  (`<chooseMovie>`)

The props `'api_res_movie_list'` and `'showList'` that are defined in the promise of the axios  `GET` appear as `undefined` on my child component, even if they are assigned to the correct value in my parent component. I think it's because the child component is rendered before being passed the props... Is it because I use  `v-show` and not  `v-if`? I'm a little confused concerning the specific rules and best practice of props passing...

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question

Comment: Not seeing any props added to your `<chooseMovie>` component in the template. It should look something like `<component-name prop-name="something" :bound-prop-name="somethingElse">`

Comment: Best you read the documentation ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments you have to pass props in the component like following:

```
<chooseMovie :your-data="api_res_movie_list"></chooseMovie>
```

You can get more details about this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).